# Rails - Can't select input loaded with cocoon (dynamically loaded) in iOS7

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I'm running into a really weird occurrence where any form fields loaded onto my page using cocoon (dynamically loaded with jQuery) won't bring up the keyboard (can't be selected) in iOS 7. Has anyone ever seen anything like this?

Comment: Please explain what you mean: "in ios7"? Is that a browser running on ios 7? Which browser? Or a view inside an app? At least inside the cocoon code i do not special depending on any platform, i would assume browsers would hide this/handle this. On the other hand: do you have specific behaviour linked to the client platform?

Comment: We tried it on multiple iOS7 devices using both safari and chrome with the same results (not a native app). I'm wondering if it is a bug with iOS7? iOS 8 works just fine on both of those browsers.